# how would I access attributes of a class, from within another class

Tags: c++, oop, ncurses

I am coding a terminal based game in c++ using the ncurses library, and I would like the enemy class to be able to access the players location which I can access from within my main function using `p->yLoc` and `p->xLoc`, however, I cannot access these variables from within my `enemy::move` function, as it just returns the error `p was not declared in this scope.`
Here is my code:

enemy.h:

```
#ifndef _ENEMY_H_
#define _ENEMY_H_
#include "player.h"
#include <unistd.h>


void Enemy::move(){
    int playerY, playerX;
    int yMv, xMv;
    while (1){
        playerY = p->yLoc;
        playerX = p->xLoc;
        if (playerY > yLoc) {
            mvdown();
        } else if (playerY < yLoc) {
            mvup();
        }

        if (playerX > xLoc){
            mvright();
        } else if (playerX < xLoc) {
            mvleft();
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

player.h

```
#ifndef _PLAYER_H_
#define _PLAYER_H_


class Player {
    public:
        Player(WINDOW * win, int y, int x, char c);
        
        void mvup();
        void mvdown();
        void mvleft();
        void mvright();
        int getmv();
        void display();
        int xLoc, yLoc, xMax, yMax;
    private:
        char character; 
        WINDOW * curwin;
};

Player::Player(WINDOW * win, int y, int x, char c){
    curwin = win;
    yLoc = y;
    xLoc = x; 
    getmaxyx(curwin, yMax, xMax);
    keypad(curwin, true);
    character = c;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include "player.h"
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "enemy.h"
#include <thread>

using namespace std; // I understand this is bad practice

int main(){
    
    // starts ncurses
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    int yMax, xMax;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, yMax, xMax); 

    WINDOW * playwin = newwin(20, 50, (yMax/2)-10, 10);
    box(playwin, 0, 0);
    refresh();
    wrefresh(playwin);
    if (nodelay (playwin, 1) == ERR) {
            // an error has occurred
    }
    Player * p = new Player(playwin, 1, 1, '@'); // params: (window to display in, starting y, starting x, character to display)
    Enemy * e = new Enemy(playwin, 10, 10, 'x'); // same here
    
    thread enemyLoop(&Enemy::move, e); // start the movement for the enemy in a different thread
    while(p->getmv() != 'x'){ // leave the game with the key x
        // updates the location of the two sprites, and refreshes the window.
        p->display();
        e->display();
        wrefresh(playwin);
    }

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never defined  `p` inside `Enemy::move` so how will you be able to use it? You only have a `p` inside `main`.

Answer (score 3):

If `Enemy::move` is supposed to know about the other players location then you have to pass the player as argument:

```
void Enemy::move(const Player &p)

e->move(*p);
```

Then the function can access the players position.

Note: why are you allocating the player and enemy on the heap. there really is no need for that.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that will break the requirements of `thread enemyLoop(&Enemy::move, e);` used later. Perhaps pass the `Player` pointer to the `Enemy `constructor?

Comment: If you think that is the only thing that multithreading will break in that code then I pitty you.

Comment: I have taken your advice, however, now, in ```Enemy::move```, using p.yLoc only returns the value that would have been given when the parameter was first passed in - so, despite the player's position changing, p.yLoc, and p.xLoc don't change.

Comment: You have to pass `Player` as a pointer. `std::thread` will by default copy reference parameters, so pass by ref and pass by value is the same thing

Comment: You should be passing `std::shared_ptr<Player>` and you need mutexes